# DataTable Row Count Returning 2 when only one VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable, count, row

I upload an excel file with only one row and one column or an empty excel file. I put this data into a datatable. I then do datatable.rows.count and it always gives me 2. Unless there are more than two records, then it gives an accurate count. Help?

Comment: Would you be able to post your code (or a sample)? If folks can see the code, they will be more likely to see what's going on & help with the issue....

Answer (score 0):

(Presuming that you may actually have a header in your Excel document) This could be because it is counting your header as a row. In your connection string please specify HDR in Extended Properties like so:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\test.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

More information here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

If you are using ODBC as opposed to OleDB to connect then your connection string and drivers will be slightly different: http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-excel-odbc-driver/